# How to trigger file removal with FilePond

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I have FilePond (via React) configured to upload multiple files, to receive those files on the back-end, store them, and show them properly when revisiting the page.

```
let server = {
  url: '/mypath',
  process: '/mypath',
  revert: '/mypath'
};

<FilePond
  server={server}
  allowMultiple={true}
  allowRevert={true}
  files={current_files}
/>
```

Using a Python back-end, this works fine for uploads:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    # handle request.FILES.get("filepond")
```

Now I want to implement DELETE, so I add `allowRemove={true}` to the FilePond instance and a `revert: /path` to the `server` configuration. What I expect to happen is that when user clicks the X, FilePond sends a DELETE request. But nothing happens - user clicking X does not send *any* request at all to the registered endpoint. I did find that I can add:

`onremovefile={(file) => handleRemove(file)}`

and if I make a `handleRemove()` React function, it is called with the `file` object. But this seems hacky - shouldn't clicking X automatically contact the registered the endpoint?

Should I proceed to send a DELETE manually from my `handleRemove()` function, or am I missing something in my configuration? The docs imply that a "revert" actions triggers DELETE when `revert` is defined on the server object.

Answer (score 2):

Try **useRef** hook.

This sample is when the file is successfully uploaded and will get removed right away.

this should work on your case.

```
const filePondRef = useRef(null)
<FilePond ref={filePondRef} onprocessfile={handleOnProcessFile}/>
```

then inside on your **onprocessfile** handler

```
const handleOnProcessFile = (error, file) => {
  if (error) {
    return;
  }

  filePondRef.current.removeFile(file);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<FilePond server={'./api'}>
```

When FilePond wants to upload a file it sends a `POST` request to `./api`

When FilePond wants to revert a file upload it sends a `DELETE` request to `./api`

`allowRemove` does not exist (maybe you meant to write `allowRevert`?).

To send the revert request to a different endpoint you can pass a different URL to the `revert` property of the `server` object.

```
<FilePond server={{ url:'./api', revert:'/revert' }>
```

Now FilePond calls `./api` to upload the file and `./api/revert` to revert the file.

Comment: I don't see `src=` mentioned anywhere in the documentation. It specifies `server=`, which is what I'm using. To be sure, I switched to `src=` but it still doesn't contact the server at all (no activity in Django terminal when clicking the X).

"When FilePond wants to revert a file upload it sends a DELETE request to ./api"

It should! But it's not. This is the essence of my question.

"maybe you meant to write allowRevert"

Yes, sorry. Had started with that, later tried allowRemove on someone's rec, but neither work. Question updated with current configuration. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW I did get it working by calling `axios.delete()` from my `handleRemove()` function, but again, it feels hacky and wonder why I can't get it working as documented.

Comment: @shacker sorry, meant to write `server` instead of `src`, corrected now.

Comment: @shacker if the file has just been uploaded clicking the X should call the revert method do you see the request in your dev tools network tab?

Comment: Nope, no activity in the Network tab, and nothing in my server console. No activity whatsoever. Hence this post!

Comment: @shacker if you open an issue on the GH repo ( http://github.com/pqina/filepond ) and post a test case I'm happy to take a look

Answer (score 0):

i have look around for this for long long time but i come up with manual way of remove list item after successful update.

```
 onload: (response) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
                $("li").remove("[data-filepond-item-state=processing-complete]");
             }, 1500);

       },
```